# GofChisquarePower solve_power

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have some issues with understanding function from statsmodels **GofChisquarePower.solve_power** .
Also there is no details in the documentation about it. As I understand this function, it works in the following way:

1. We provide all parameters except one to **GofChisquarePower.solve_power (effect_size = None, nobs = None, alpha = None, power = None, n_bins = 2)**
2. Then the missing parameter will be calculated based on the other input values.

However, i still have several questions:

a) What does parameter **n_bins** mean?

b) Can we use this function for cases with multiple testing? E.g by changing alpha(type I error) with bonferroni correction?